# Custom alert dialog not displaying JSON data from Asynctask's Post Execute

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have a weird problem with showing my custom alert dialog from inside my async task's post execute method. When the program is run, the progress dialog from my pre-execute is first of all dismissed in the post execute before I then display my custom alert dialog which displays parsed JSON data. But the custom alert dialog does not show up at all, after dismissing the progress dialog.

Please, can anyone help with possible reasons why that's happening? Here is the code from my post exec method.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    loginDialog.dismiss();
    jsonstring = result;

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        fname = JO.getString("firstname");
        lname = JO.getString("lastname");
        possessionqty = JO.getString("possessionQty");
        email = JO.getString("email");
        status = JO.getString("status");

        mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.studentinfo_alertdialog, null);

        studentIDheader = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        studentfullname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        studentpossessionqty = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        studentemail = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        studentstatus = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        studentIDheader.setText(validatedID);
        studentfullname.setText("Full Name: " + fname + " " + lname);
        studentpossessionqty.setText("Possession Qty: " + possessionqty);
        studentemail.setText("Email: " + email);
        studentstatus.setText("Status: " + status);

        mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        mBuilder.setView(mView);

        dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seem alright from the point of working with Android API.
My guess will be that there is an Exception thrown either by JSON-parser or some of the views are null.

Comment: Honestly, Your response was all I needed to open my eyes. You were right. An exception was thrown and I fixed it right now. Its working. Thank you so much.